# what is 499 in http response GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 499

Tags: http, web, https, python-requests

I am giving a python requests to a server using requests package. When analyzed the log of the same, I saw `https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 499`. I confused about the status code.
What is 200 and 499? which represent actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

499 represents Content-Length and it is not the status code.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 200 means the connection was successful. When you make an HTTP request you usually want a response code of 200.

HTTP error 499 simply means that the client shut off in the middle of processing the request through the server. The 499 error code puts better light that something happened with the client, that is why the request cannot be done.

Comment: Sometimes, I have seen "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9430. what is 9430? Where did I get the information for second status codes?

Answer (score 0):

here you see status code using the below example

```
import requests                                      
  
response = requests.get('https://example.in/')      # call GET requests

print(response.status_code)                         # print status code
#<Response [200]>
```

Response 200 indicate the request has succeeded
and
Response 499 indicates an error that the client shuts off in the middle of processing the request through the server.

Comment: Sometimes, For successful response I have seen "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9430. what is 9430? Where did I get the information for second status codes?